# What can I use to repair a beach glass pendant?

Tags: glass, jewelry

My wife got a small painted white [beach-glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sea_glass) (also known as sea glass) pendant while we were travelling out east (Canada) years ago. I got a good size chip on it somehow recently. The chip is about 1cm<sup>2</sup>. I thought about just using some epoxy resin but that would dry clear unlike the translucent appearance of beach glass. While I could rough that surface I do not know how it will look with glass.

I do not have much to experiment with so I was looking for alternate/supporting ideas.

[image: Glass pendant with chip on edge]

What can I do to try and repair a large clean chip of beach glass while *trying* to maintain its normal appearance? I no longer have the shard so gluing it back on is not an option.

Comment: An image would help, here. I imagine the location _might_ have an impact on possible solutions (especially alternatives)

Comment: Of course it would not hurt. Was trying to avoid adding an image to everything unless it actually helped. The chip is on the edge. I will get an image once I am home.

Comment: @CreationEdge I totally did it when I said I would.

Comment: You were technically at home, I presume ;)

Answer (score 2):

Best way will be to use resin and mix it with some pigment. Some [resellers](https://shop.resinobsession.com/collections/colorants) even advertise their resin colors and pigments saying that they produce an opaque look similar to sea or beach glass.

Basically any pigment of the color of the pendent mixed with some white pigment will work. However some trials are necessary to obtain a coloring matching the pendent.

In the end sanding the surface of the colored epoxy with a very fine grit sandpaper will also provide the surface structure of sea glass.

Comment: Since his damage is a surface shard, and not a gouge, I imagine this would be more effective, as the resin wouldn't need to be very thick